# Different versions of the determinant theorem about $n$-covectors

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, differential-geometry, differential-topology, multilinear-algebra

Here are 4 versions of one theorem:

1. **Guillemin and Pollack**:

> [image]
>
> (Note that $A^\ast T(v_1,\dots,v_k)=T(Av_1,\dots,Av_k)$.)

2. **Lee**:

> [image]

3. **Spivak**:

> [image]

4. **Tu**:

> [image]

I can see that Tu's version implies Spivak's version because the former works for all $v_1,\dots,v_n$ whereas the latter works for $v_1,\dots v_n$ a basis (note that Spivak's $(a_{ij})$ is the transpose of Tu's $A$, but this doesn't matter). Also, Lee's version implies Guillemin and Pollack's as well as Spivak's. (To see why it implies Spivak's version, let $(v_1,\dots,v_n)$ be a basis for $V$ and define $T$ by $T(v_i)=w_i$ for all $i$; then if $A$ is the matrix of $T$ w.r.t. this basis, then $A=(a_{ij})^t$ where $(a_{ij})$ is Spivak's matrix.)

That's all equivalences I can see so far. But they all seem so similar. Are they all equivalent? If not, is there a subset of the set of the above theorems the elements of which are pairwise equivalent?